# Regex and preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

I want to do a regex to match one of these strings: `add`, `delete`, `edit`, `read`.

My regex has to only accept, the below strings (not others words):

```
    add

    delete 

    edit

    read

,
```

Here's my current regex but it does not work as expected:

```
#(add|delete|read|edit),#
```

**Edit**

I want to my preg_match return true if in my string they are:

```
read
delete
add
edit
,
```

If they are other word or symbol, return false.

Thanks you all.

Comment: Show the code you did plz.

Comment: Ce serait sympa si tu repondais aux questions... =/

Comment: Could you show us some valid and invalid strings?

Comment: Thanks you Jerry! Your regex work fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
^(?:(?:add|delete|read|edit)|,)$
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/qW1yA2)

I used a group to limit the choices first to your individual strings, then the anchors `^` and `$` to ensure there's nothing else in the string you're testing it against.

```
$words = array('add', 'delete', ',', 'reading', 'edit', 'read', 'gedit');

foreach ($words as $word) {
    if (preg_match('#^(?:(?:add|delete|read|edit)|,)$#', $word)) {
        echo "$word: Matched!\n";
    } else {
        echo "$word: Not matched!\n";
    }
}
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/XCk3SK)

Answer (score 3):

Seems you did a minor error. The pattern should basically work. Example:

```
$str = <<<EOF
add, delete foo edit read bar add
hello world
EOF;

preg_match_all('#add|delete|read|edit|,#', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  array(6) {
    [0] =>
    string(3) "add"
    [1] =>
    string(1) ","
    [2] =>
    string(6) "delete"
    [3] =>
    string(4) "edit"
    [4] =>
    string(4) "read"
    [5] =>
    string(3) "add"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you konw how I can do to check with `preg_match()` if there are other word ? I want to only just accept the currents words ?

Comment: sorry, I don't get you. Maybe you try in French and someone translates? (I don't speak French :)

Answer (score -1):

```
^(?:add|delete|read|edit)$
```

what are those hashes doing there btw ?

demo here

http://regex101.com/r/zX2yU8

Comment: Those hashes are delimiters

Comment: If you're going to put anchors around, you need to group the options: http://regex101.com/r/xP2zN0